# How can I use doctrine find method in repository

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

This code is working fine in controller

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getEntityManager();
$entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Child')->find($id);
```

Now I have custom `Repository` class

I want to know that how can use that in there

```
function getUser()
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();
    $entity = $em->getRepository('AcmeUserBundle:Child')->find($id);
}
```

Do I still need to use `getRepository` in `Repository` as well or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the method is in `Repository` class, then you could just use `$this`.

```
$enity = $this->find($id);
```

Comment: Suppose from where it is getting `find` Method , i have not defined that in my repository. Is that method always available

Comment: @john110016 `$this` means the current Repository, if you want to use other Repository, then you need to get the Repository first.